# How to use same field from a table twice in one query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: calls and employees. In the **calls** tables I have a field `enter_emp_id` and another `follow_emp_id`. They hold the values for which employee entered the call and which employee is assigned to the call. My second table **employees** has `employee_id` and `employee` fields. I am able to write a query to show results with an employee name for who entered the call, but not who it is assigned to. I do have other values in the query, but I need to get the 2nd employee name to show in the results. Here is what I am using so far:

```
SELECT 
  `calls`.`call_id`,
  `calls`.`enter_date`,
  `call_state`.`call_state`,
  `customers`.`customer_name`,
  `calls`.`comments`,
  `employees`.`employee`,
  `call_reasons`.`call_reason`
FROM
  `customers`
  INNER JOIN `calls` ON (`customers`.`customer_id` = `calls`.`customer_id`)
  INNER JOIN `employees` ON (`employees`.`employee_id` = `calls`.`enter_emp_id`)
  INNER JOIN `call_state` ON (`call_state`.`call_state_id` = `calls`.`call_state_id`)
  INNER JOIN `call_reasons` ON (`call_reasons`.`call_reason_id` = `calls`.`call_reason_id`)
WHERE
  `calls`.`call_id` = $call_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join to the employee table TWICE... once for each employee id association, and use the ALIAS of the respective to get the values intended.  And aliasing the tables and removal of unnecessary `tick` marks not required.  Only needed for possible reserved word conflicts.

```
SELECT 
      c.call_id,
      c.enter_date,
      cs.call_state,
      cust.customer_name,
      c.comments,
      entered.employee,
      assigned.employee as AssignedEmployee,
      cr.call_reason
   FROM
      calls c
         INNER JOIN customers cust
            ON c.customer_id = cust.customer_id
         INNER JOIN employees entered 
            ON c.enter_emp_id = entered.employee_id 
         INNER JOIN employees assigned 
            ON c.enter_emp_id = assigned.employee_id
         INNER JOIN call_state cs 
            ON c.call_state_id = cs.call_state_id
         INNER JOIN call_reasons cr
            ON c.call_reason_id = cr.call_reason_id 
   WHERE
      c.call_id = $call_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, got me on the right track had to add assigned.employee to the SELECT portion but the following query did what I needed, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I hope i understand you problem. You can use `AS` to change or shorten table name for sql usage

```
  SELECT 
      `calls`.`call_id`,
      `calls`.`enter_date`,
      `call_state`.`call_state`,
      `customers`.`customer_name`,
      `calls`.`comments`,
      `employees`.`employee`,
      `assigned`.`employee` as assigned_employee,
      `call_reasons`.`call_reason`
    FROM
      `customers`
      INNER JOIN `calls` ON (`customers`.`customer_id` = `calls`.`customer_id`)
      INNER JOIN `employees` ON (`employees`.`employee_id` = `calls`.`enter_emp_id`)
      INNER JOIN `employees` AS `assigned` ON (`assigned`.`employee_id` = `calls`.`follow_emp_id`)
      INNER JOIN `call_state` ON (`call_state`.`call_state_id` = `calls`.`call_state_id`)
      INNER JOIN `call_reasons` ON (`call_reasons`.`call_reason_id` = `calls`.`call_reason_id`)
    WHERE
      `calls`.`call_id` = $call_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the following worked:
SELECT 
      c.call_id,
      c.enter_date,
      cs.call_state,
      cust.customer_name,
      c.comments,
      entered.employee,
      entered.employee,
      cr.call_reason
   FROM
      calls c
         INNER JOIN customers cust
            ON c.customer_id = cust.customer_id
         INNER JOIN employees entered 
            ON c.enter_emp_id = entered.employee_id 
         INNER JOIN employees assigned 
            ON c.enter_emp_id = assigned.employee_id
         INNER JOIN call_state cs 
            ON c.call_state_id = cs.call_state_id
         INNER JOIN call_reasons cr
            ON c.call_reason_id = cr.call_reason_id 
   WHERE
      c.call_id = $call_id;